# Is it necessary to abort on AJAX timeout?

Tags: jquery

I have an ajax GET request with a 2 second timeout. I don't want the request to still be hanging out there if the request times out. At 2 seconds, I just want to stop everything.

I'm wondering if it is necessary to call `abort()` if timeout has been reached, or does reaching the timeout threshold automatically abort everything...?

```
request = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            timeout: 2000, 
            success: function (data) {

                // do some stuff

            },
            error: function(x, t, m) {

                if(t==="timeout") {
                    request.abort(); // is this necessary?
                    // do some other stuff

                } // end if timeout
            } // end error function
        }); // end ajax
```

Comment: no, not necessary to abort, the request will be cancelled when the timeout is reached.

Comment: jQuery would be doing a pretty poor job if it didn't do this for you.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to be sure. I couldn't find a definitive answer anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not necessary. Internally, jQuery will `abort` the XHR for you when the timeout is hit.

If you check the [source of $.ajax](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.ajax) you can see this in action:

```
// Timeout
if (s.async && s.timeout > 0) {
    timeoutTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        jqXHR.abort("timeout");
    },
    s.timeout);
}
```